# What is the easiest way to convert list with str into list with int?

Tags: python, string, integer

What is the easiest way to convert list with `str` into list with `int` in Python? 
For example, we have to convert `['1', '2', '3']` to `[1, 2, 3]`. Of course, we can use a `for` loop, but it's too easy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Python 2.x:

```
map(int, ["1", "2", "3"])
```

Python 3.x (in 3.x, `map` returns an iterator, not a list as in 2.x):

```
list(map(int, ["1", "2", "3"]))
```

`map` documentation: [2.6](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), [3.1](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: I'm under the impression that `map` is generally disliked. It was even almost removed from Python 3.

Comment: @pafcu I don't understand that. That sort of functionality is essential for functional programming...

Answer (score 19):

```
[int(i) for i in str_list]
```

Comment: +1 I really like `map`, but generators are way more readable.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use list comprehensions:

```
new = [int(i) for i in old]
```

Or the `map()` builtin function:

```
new = map(int, old)
```

Or the `itertools.imap()` function, which will provide a speedup in some cases but in this case just spits out an iterator, which you will need to convert to a list (so it'll probably take the same amount of time):

```
import itertools as it
new = list(it.imap(int, old))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your strings are not only numbers (ie. u''), you can use :

```
new = [int(i) for i in ["1", "2", "3"] if isinstance(i, int) or isinstance(i, (str, unicode)) and i.isnumeric()]
```

Answer (score 2):

If It is array and has installed numpy. We can used below code as well.

```
import numpy as np

np.array(['1', '2', '3'],dtype=int)
```