# Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, transformation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to convert list with str into list with int? =)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424412/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-list-with-str-into-list-with-int)

Is it possible to transform:

a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

to

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
result = [int(x) for x in a]
```

This is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map` to apply a function to each element of a list, and a get the resulting list (Python 2.x) / iterable (Python 3.x) back.

```
map(int, a)
```

It could be done with list comprehension too.

```
[int(x) for x in a]
```