# Python: How do I convert an array of strings to an array of numbers?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to convert list with str into list with int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424412/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-list-with-str-into-list-with-int)

current array: `['1','-1','1']`
desired array: `[1,-1,1]`

Comment: for item in array
       item*=1

Comment: Why do you call 'array' what are lists ? See: (http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array)

Comment: MATHY people call Python lists an array.  A 2-d list/array is a matrix. I believe the origin is from linear algebra.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use `int` which converts a string to an int, inside a list comprehension, like this:

```
desired_array = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in current_array]
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can use this method for casting to a class as well, e.g. `for instance in [MyClass(name) for name in list_of_names]:`

Comment: The OP said numbers... so a better answer would be `[float(x) for x in current_array]` which also handles non-integer values

Answer (score 59):

[List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are the way to go (see [@sepp2k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306079/python-how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-numbers/5306094#5306094)). Possible alternative with [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
list(map(int, ['1','-1','1']))
```

Comment: A perfect example why declarative style might be much better than imperative IMHO.

Comment: It however does not return a list, but a map. At least after I did

x = map(int, ['1','-1','1'])

I could not call len(x).

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I remember python

```
list = ['1' , '2', '3']
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list)):
    t = int(list[i])
    list2.append(t)

print list2
```

**edit**: looks like the other responses work out better