# Mapping Int to a List - Python

Tags: python, string, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: How do I convert an array of strings to an array of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306079/python-how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-numbers)

I am trying to map a list of strings to Int, and when I map the Int function it is splitting 2 digit numbers into 2 item lists:

I have the following code:

```
>>> MyList
['10', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>>> MyList = [map(int,x) for x in MyList]
>>> MyList
[[1, 0], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

What is the correct way to get a list that looks like this:

```
[10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `map(int, ...` directly on the list:

```
map(int, MyList)
```

or, in most circumstances, use a list comprehension:

```
[int(x) for x in MyList]
```

but not both.

`map` applies the function to every item in the iterable by itself -- that is its purpose.

Similarly, a list comprehension runs the expression on every item in the iterable, so you don't need `map`, just the expression you want to run every time.

Comment: Also note that in python3.x, `map` returns an iterator, not a list.  So in python2.x the 2 things above are equivalent whereas in python3.x there is a slight difference.

Comment: @mgilson Good note, but we know in this case he's on Python 2 because of the code in his answer.