# How do i take formatted input in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to take an input say 7 8 9 5 12 17 as separate integers in an array ar[]. I have tried 
`a=input() 
ar.append(a.split(" "))` 
but it just stores the numbers as strings. And I can't find a way to convert these integers directly while appending. Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a proper python `list` object, you can do

```
ar = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

Otherwise, Do it this way

```
ar = map(int, input().split())
```

You can also strip extra whitespace if needed. Do

```
ar = map(int, input().strip().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
a=input()
ar = map(int, a.split(" "))
```

See [Python: How do I convert an array of strings to an array of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306079/python-how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by **list comprehension**.

```
ar = [int(x) for x in a.strip().split()]
```

Here, we first `strip` the whitespace from the end and the beginning of the input `a` and then perform `split()`. It will return list of all the numbers in `a` as strings. Then using list comprehension, we convert all the numbers obtained as string to `integers`.

**Example:**

For `a` as  `' 12 34 45 12 56 '`,

```
>>> ar = [int(x) for x in a.strip().split()]
>>> ar
[12, 34, 45, 12, 56]
```

**Note:** `split()` operation returns a list of strings. We ourselves will have to perform the conversion of those strings to integers.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in function `map(function, iterable, ..)` can be used here to apply the `int()` function all over.

```
ar = map(int, a.split(" "))
```