# Sorting column B Google Sheets API (Python)

Tags: python, google-sheets

If anybody could assist me that would be great. I've been trying to print a high scores list and every method I've tried to sort the scores isn't working and I don't understand what I keep doing wrong.

```
def show_high_scores():
    """
    shows top 5 highest scores to the user
    """
    scores_col = SHEET.worksheet('high_scores').col_values(2)
    scores_data = scores_col[1:]
    sorted_scores = sorted(scores_data, reverse=True)

    names_col = SHEET.worksheet('high_scores').col_values(1)
    names_data = names_col[1:]

    print('\nHigh Scores\n')

    for i in range(5):
        print(str(names_data[i]) + "\t" + str(sorted_scores[i]))
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add the values of `scores_col`, show the current results and the expected results.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes The issue seems to be that the order only seems to take into account the first digit. So scores can appear as "9, 9, 7, 13, 10". I presume this is because the 1 in 13 is lower than the other numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `scores_data` is a list of strings, so `sorted()` will sort them alphabetically. As you've noticed, it sorts using the first digit of the number rather than the numeric value.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5306094), you can easily convert the list `scores_data` to integers using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```py
scores_numeric = [int(score_str) for score_str in scores_data]
```

Then you can just sort the new numeric array instead:

```py
sorted_scores = sorted(scores_numeric, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been staring at this for far too long!